# How to stage chunks non-interactively in git?

Tags: git

I know I can add chunks using any of the following commands

```
git add -i
git add --patch
git add --edit
```

But I can get all chunks for a file

```
git --no-pager diff file1 > /tmp/stageme
```

I can see three chunks I want only the first and last chunks, so I remove the second chunk the file `/tmp/stageme`

**How I can stage those chunks in a command?** I mean, how can I stage the info from `/tmp/stageme`?

Comment: What you want is (I believe) `git add -e`, which has been in git since 1.6.4 so is probably in your version.

Comment: Yes I want that behavior but I want use a file for that, I dont want edit the file manually

Answer (score 2):

I found I can do it the the `git apply` command

```
git apply --cached /tmp/patchme
```