# How do I identify & list unique hunks in a git commit?

Tags: git, awk, diff, unified-diff

I have a commit with a large number (hundreds) of similar [hunks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Unified_format), and I'd like to list each unique hunk in the commit in order to compare them.

I wrote the following GNU awk script, which writes each hunk to a unique file (`hunk-[md5-of-hunk].txt`):

```
BEGIN {
  hunk = ""
  buildhunk = 0
}

function writeHunk() {
  if (length(hunk) > 0) {
    print hunk > "hunk.tmp"
    close("hunk.tmp")
    cmd = "cat hunk.tmp | md5"
    cmd | getline md5
    close(cmd)
    if (!(md5 in hunkfiles)) {
      hunkfilename = "hunk-" md5 ".txt"
      print hunk > hunkfilename
      hunkfiles[md5] = hunkfilename
    }
  }
}

/^@@|^diff/ {
  writeHunk()
  hunk = ""
  buildhunk = ($1 == "@@") ? 1 : 0
}

/^[ +-]/ {
  if (buildhunk) {
    hunk = hunk $0 "\n"
  }
}

END {
  writeHunk()
  system("rm hunk.tmp")
  for (md5 in hunkfiles) {
    print hunkfiles[md5]
  }
}
```

I then run this with `git show [commit-SHA] | awk -f my_script.awk`, which creates & lists the resulting files. It works for my purposes, but is there a way to do this more efficiently using git's plumbing commands.

#### Example

Suppose the commit's patch looks like this (reduced to 1 line of context below for clarity's sake):

```
diff --git a/file1.txt b/file1.txt
index a3fb2ed..4d6f587 100644
--- a/file1.txt
+++ b/file1.txt
@@ -3,2 +3,3 @@ context
 context
+added line
 context
@@ -7,2 +8,3 @@ context
 context
+added line
 context
@@ -11,2 +13,3 @@ context
 context
+added line
 context
@@ -15,2 +18,3 @@ context
 context
+different added line
 context
@@ -19,2 +23,3 @@ context
 context
+different added line
 context
@@ -23,2 +28,3 @@ context
 context
+different added line
 context
@@ -27,2 +33,3 @@ context
 context
+even more different added line
 context
@@ -31,2 +38,3 @@ context
 context
+even more different added line
 context
```

I want to be able to identity that there are only 3 unique hunks, and see what they are. Namely:

Unique hunk 1:

```
 context
+added line
 context
```

Unique hunk 2:

```
 context
+different added line
 context
```

Unique hunk 3:

```
 context
+even more different added line
 context
```

Comment: There is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993074/stage-hunk-non-interactively-in-git), but it never got answered.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks, I looked at that question, and it's similar in that both concern hunks, but my question is more about identifying & listing unique hunks in a commit, while that question is about non-interactively adding hunks in some scripted way. I'll update my question to clarity.

Comment: I agree, that's why I didn't mark as a duplicate, but I think a solution that programmatically gives you your hunks separately could be used to solve that other problem as well.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Agreed & appreciated :) I have a feeling git already does this somewhere in its plumbing. I'm hoping someone who knows git's internals well enough has some simple one-liner to list a commit's unique hunks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commits are *snapshots*, and as such, they don't *have* diff hunks.

Diffs, of course, do have diff hunks.  So if you have just one commit, you cannot do this at all.  You need *two* commits.  You then simply diff them and do what you are doing.

Note that `git show <commit-hash>` really means `git diff <parent or parents of commit> <commit-hash>`.  If the specified commit is a merge commit, this produces a *combined diff*, which is probably not useful for your purposes since combined diffs intentionally omit many changes entirely.  You might want to run an explicit diff against the commit's *first* parent only (to view only changes brought in as part of the merge).

There are some parts of Git that internally do something like what you're doing, for `git rerere` and `git patch-id`.  However, they don't do *exactly* what you're doing: for `rerere` they record only diff hunks where there was a merge conflict, and match up those diff hunks (saved by hash ID and file name) with resolutions recorded later.  For `patch-id` they strip off line numbers and white-space but accumulate the entire set of changes from a commit into one big piece.  It might be nice if Git had a bit of plumbing that did the `git patch-id` part hunk by hunk, independent of computing the overall patch ID for the commit, but it doesn't.

Comment: thanks! You're of course right that commits don't have hunks in their own right, but rather the hunks are a product of comparing 2 commits (and that the hunks themselves are context-sensitive). Supposing I isolate the hunks myself, do you see any advantage of using `patch-id` in place of md5 to ID the hunks?

Comment: @tavnab: Might be a bit faster, might not. See whether you like what it does to white space. Also you'll get sha-1s rather than md5s, so you get a few more bits of hash (160 bits, vs 128). None of these seem big arguments one way or another, except for treatment of white space.

Comment: I think I'll stick with md5 for now, but good to know I have the whitespace-stripping option of `patch-id` in case I need it.