# Can git's interactive hunk staging be partly automated using regex patterns?

Tags: git

Git allows you to interactively stage hunks when you pass the `-p` or `--patch` option to `git add`, as documented [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---patch).

Consider the following example, modified from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31993074/1412255)

```
-this is the first line
+this is the first change, don't stage it!
-this is the second line
+this is the second change, stage it!
-this is the third line
+this is the third change, ask me!
```

In this example, I'd like to do something like `git add -p --automatic-y "second" --automatic-n "first"` so that it automatically stages the second change, doesn't stage the first change, and only asks me about the last one. (this example has single lines but the matching could easily be multiline)

I know that this functionality isn't built into git. But is there at least a command which allows me to retrieve and then stage a hunk programatically, so that I could perhaps write a script to perform the partial staging and then run`git add -p` with only the undecided hunks?

Comment: The linked question has the same title but asks for a different functionality (wants to stage hunk by number) so I do not think my question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to view the feature of `git add -p` :

1. take the output of `git diff`
2. for each chunk in that diff, run an interactive prompt to ask if it should put that chunk in the index
3. apply the patch file built from your choices in 2. (*)

If you want to replace `2.` with your custom step :

write a script, which

1. takes the output of `git diff -- that/file`
2. split the output into chunks (e.g : blocks of lines starting with `@@ -[digit]+,[digit]+ ...`)
3. apply whatever actions you want, based on matching the content of each block, or on some command line flags, and possibly displaying individual chunks to the user and asking for input, in order to build a patch file of what will be applied
4. apply that patch file

---

(*) this is not entirely true technically, but is close enough

---

I'd say the main difficulty ahead of you is anticipating what `git diff` will group together as a chunk.

For example : if we take your example litterally, chances are `git diff` would actually present you with one single chunk :

```
-this is the first line
-this is the second line
-this is the third line
+this is the first change, don't stage it!
+this is the second change, stage it!
+this is the third change, ask me!
```